# Auto-populating new panel on button click

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, ms-word

and thank you for viewing my thread. I have a project I am creating in Visual Studio 2010 with C#. It is basically a Word minutes template. I have a form that the user fills out, which then goes to the word document. I have gotten stuck with a problem. I will try my best to explain. I have a section where the user keeps entering data on a subject. I need to be able to have the form continuously populate the same panel until the user clicks the check box which moves the user to the next question. Right now, I have the panels on top of each other and have them hide until the user checks the checkmark and moves on. My problem is that I have no idea how many possible panels will be needed. The user could have only 5, or the user could have up to 100 if needed. Is there an easier way to have the form populate panels automatically? I will attach a screenshot below. Thanks for all the help!

[image: Example of form]

Comment: This is not ASP.Net; please re-tag.

Comment: my apologies. it is corrected.